# Как правильно оформить цитаты в следующих случаях?

Tags: пунктуация

Да и марксово «деньги — товар — деньги» еще никто не отменил, потому что все-таки «сначала — деньги, а потом — стулья». В общем, «без денег жить нельзя на свете, нет», как бы этого кому-то не хотелось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Знаки препинания расставлены верно, это цитаты, встроенные в текст.
2. Как бы этого кому-то ни хотелось. Это придаточное уступительное, усилительная частица НИ.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. А есть ли в Интернете где-либо ссылки на подобное оформление цитат?

Comment: У Лопатина (знаки препинания при цитатах) http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139